# Is the performance of a deep learning model affected if it has "seen" the same test images before?

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I am working with the YOLOv3 model for an object detection task. I am using pre-trained weights that were generated for the COCO dataset, however, I have my own data for the problem I am working on. According to my knowledge, using those trained weights as a starting point for my own model should not have any effect on the performance of the model once it is trained on an entirely different dataset (right?).

My question is: will the model give "honest" results if I train it multiple times and test it on the same test set each time, or would it have better performance since it has already been exposed to those test images during an earlier experiment? I've heard people say things like "the model has already seen that data", does that apply in my case?

Answer (score 0):

For hyper-parameter selection, evaluation of different models, or evaluating during training, you should always use a validation set.

You are not allowed to use the test set until the end!

The whole purpose of test data is to get an estimation of the performance after the deployment. When you use it during training to train your model or evaluate your model, you expose that data. For example, based on the accuracy of the test set, you decide to increase the number of layers.

Now, your performance will be increased on the test set. However, it will come with a price!
Your estimation on the test set becomes biased, and you no longer be able to use that estimation to talk about data that your model sees after deployment.

For example, You want to train an object detector for self-driving cars, and you exposed the test set during training. Therefore, you can not use the accuracy on the test set to talk about the performance of the object detector when you put it on a car and sell it to a customer.

There is an old sentence related to this matter:

> If you torture the data enough, it will confess.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am not using the test set during training, what I meant to ask was can I use the same test set after multiple trials of training the model (on a separate training set) and expect honest results?

Comment: People usually have three sets: training, validation, test.

Many people after finding the good parameters with the validation set, combine training and validation to create a bigger training set.

However, I have never seen someone that do that with test set.